# MS Excel: Standardize date into one format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on an excel file to be merged into mysql database.

Problem is my former colleague input dates in different formats from excel, so when I merged it and generate report from the system, the date is not in proper order.

Date column is free-text before, and I just change it's format to "mm/dd/yyyy" to make it standard.

Sample:

[image]

How can I make all dates to "mm/ddd/yyyy" format only on excel before merging?

I'm looking for some formula (or add-ons) because I have 1700+ rows to check so it's kinda hard to do it manually.

Comment: Which of these columns represent the current state of data?

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij "encoded from excel" column

Comment: How do you interpret `4/1/2020` as 'January 4,2020' but `1/5/2020` as `January 5,2020`? There should be a consistent rule which can be used.

Comment: You will need to go back to the original source, and ensure the dates are "real Excel dates" (e.g serial numbers with `1` = `1 Jan 1900`). Else there will be no way of telling if `1/3/2020` represents `1-Mar-2020` or `3-Jan-2020`

Comment: guys, the excel file was only given to my by my former colleague before she resigned, dates are only written as free-text that's why i'm having troubles formatting it. I tried to convert the cell into date format but the results are not as intended so i'm asking for help if there's any other way to standardize this or no choice but to do it manually?

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij there are dates like 11/2/2020 (Nov. 2, 2020 - too advance) which doesn't exist on our current transactions but it should be 2/11/2020 (Feb. 11, 2020)